# Loose bounding box with circular arcs

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0)  circle (1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0)  circle (1);
   \draw[red] (200:1)  arc (200:320:1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0)  circle (1);
   \draw[green] (320:1)  arc (320:560:1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[red] (200:1)  arc (200:320:1);
   \draw[green] (320:1)  arc (320:560:1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[green] (320:1)  arc (320:560:1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[red] (200:1)  arc (200:320:1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would expect the bounding box to fit tightly around the arcs. However, the picture shows a different behavior. I am sure there are experts around here who can explain me why this happens....

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When TikZ calculates the bounding box for an arc, it uses the start, end and *control* points of the Bezier curves into account. The control points usually lie outside the arc.

The following example fixes the bounding boxes by a reset of the bounding box `\pgfresetboundingbox` and setting it again with a `\draw` command without lines using some points that define the bounding box. `\draw` is used instead of `\path` or `\useasboundingbox`, because it also takes the line width into account.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0)  circle (1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0)  circle (1);
   \draw[red] (200:1)  arc (200:320:1);
   \pgfresetboundingbox
   \draw (-1, -1) (1, 1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0)  circle (1);
   \draw[green] (320:1)  arc (320:560:1);
   \pgfresetboundingbox
   \draw (-1, -1) (1, 1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[red] (200:1)  arc (200:320:1);
   \draw[green] (320:1)  arc (320:560:1);
   \pgfresetboundingbox
   \draw (-1, -1) (1, 1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[green] (320:1)  arc (320:560:1);
   \pgfresetboundingbox
   \draw (-1, 1) (1, 0) (320:1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[red] (200:1)  arc (200:320:1);
   \pgfresetboundingbox
   \draw (0, -1) (200:1) (320:1);
   \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: (+1) for giving me something useful to look up ;). But within a `pic`, for example, `\pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse` is useful. (I freely concede this question had nothing at all to do with `pic`s.)And the `fit` library can be useful if you have something less predictable than a circle. An extraterrestrial, say, or something like that ;).